# Work manager and Location updates best practice

Tags: android, android-location, android-workmanager

I'm trying to get some location updates and save them to the database.

My problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

What I do now is I start a Work Manager like this:

```
val uploadWorkRequest: PeriodicWorkRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ListenableLocationUpdateWorker>(
                15, TimeUnit.MINUTES
            ).build()

        WorkManager
            .getInstance(this)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                PERIODIC_LOCATION_TAG,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                uploadWorkRequest
            )
```

**ListenableLocationUpdateWorker** looks like this:

```
val repository = Repository(context)

private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

private val locationRequest: LocationRequest
    get() {
        return LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 5000).build()
    }


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun startWork(): ListenableFuture<Result> {
    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture {

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { lastLocation ->
            if (lastLocation != null) {
                val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this)
                        repository.Insert(locationResult)
                        it.set(Result.success())
                    }
                }
                fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                    locationRequest,
                    locationCallback,
                    Looper.getMainLooper()
                )

            } else {
                it.set(Result.failure())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main problem is that sometimes there are no location, or work manager just haven't started.

Now it works only when I open the app, so no background work here.

How do I make it right?